# How to find the Residues of $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How to find the Residues of $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}$$

So far I've wrote $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(z+i)^2(z-i)^2}$$ so $f$ has isolated singularities  at $z=\pm i$.

But I don't know what to do from here.

I know of the limit way of finding these things but that relies on either knowing the order or just calculating the derivatives but that is quite messy.

Comment: Would it be $-1/4$ by any chance for $z=i$?

Answer (score 1):

If $z_0$ is a pole of order $p$, the residue is in general given by $$Res(f,z_0) = \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{1}{(p-1)!}((z-z_0)^pf)^{(p-1)}(z)$$

Here, $i$ is a pole of order 2, hence $$Res(f,i) = \left(\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}\right)'|_{z=i}=\frac{-2}{(z+i)^3}|_{z=i}=-\frac{i}{4}$$